# .NET Core - How do you reference one IHostedService from another?

Tags: .net-core, service

I've got two hosted services in my web service: **Domain** and **ComplianceService**.  **ComplianceService** needs to reference data and methods in **Domain**, like so:

```
public ComplianceService(ILogger<ComplianceService> logger, Domain domain, IRuleRepository ruleRepository)
{
    // Initialize the service.
    this.logger = logger;
    this.domain = domain;
    this.ruleRepository = ruleRepository;
}
```

My initialization in startup.cs looks like this:

```
    // Add the dependencies.
    serviceCollection.AddSingleton<RulesActivator>()
        .AddSingleton<Accruals>()
        .AddSingleton<IRuleRepository, ComplianceRuleRepository>()
        .AddSingleton<IViolation, Violation>();

    // Add the hosted services.
    serviceCollection.AddHostedService<Domain>();
    serviceCollection.AddHostedService<ComplianceService>();
```

When I try to run this, I get this message:

`System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type 'ThetaRex.OpenBook.ServerDomain.Domain' while attempting to activate 'ThetaRex.OpenBook.WebApi.ComplianceService'.'`

If I add **Domain** to the IoC, like this:

```
    serviceCollection.AddSingleton<Domain>()
        .AddSingleton<RulesActivator>()
        .AddSingleton<Accruals>()
        .AddSingleton<IRuleRepository, ComplianceRuleRepository>()
        .AddSingleton<IViolation, Violation>();
```

It runs, but I get two copies of **Domain**.  I can force it to work like this:

```
    // Add the hosted services.
    serviceCollection.AddHostedService(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<Domain>());
    if (this.Configuration.GetValue<bool>("ComplianceEnabled"))
    {
        serviceCollection.AddHostedService<ComplianceService>();
    }
```

But this seems really clumsy and counterintuitive.  How come the *AddHostedService* can instantiate **ComplianceService**, but can't instantiate the dependent service?

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The approach shown would work given the current use case. Why not have the desired domain functionality extracted into its own concern/service and inject that into the other hosted service?

Comment: Seems like you are violating the separation of concerns here. Use separate class for functionality that you are trying to use from one service in another. And the just inject it in both hosted services.